# Salesforce Chat widget

Tags: chatter

Is there any way to make the chat widget appear inside the pages and not "external" on-top?
I want to include it in as an integral part of the pages.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware unfortunately not, you can include regular chatter feeds inside Visualforce but your options for the chat widget are much more limited

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDocid=collab_chat_admin_visualforce.htm&language=en